# Escaping URLs in an html attribute in PHP

Tags: php, security, xss

I am currently working with some existing code that takes a URL out of the request and inputs it into the source of an anchor. This is clearly an opening for XSS and using urlencoding doesn't retain the sanity of the url inside the anchor. I'm curious what the safest way to escape the data without breaking the link would be.

i.e.

```
 <? 
    $url = $_REQUEST['url'];
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '">sometext</a>'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars($url)` will convert the HTML-sensitive characters to their entity equivalents. However, it is possible to insert javascript snippets into urls as well -- details of which I am personally not knowledgeable of. A more complex solution such as [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) may assist you in covering most vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 4):

There's also `filter_var`, which has a set of predefined filters you can use, one of which I believe is for URLs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

**Edit:** Yup: Sanitize filters: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php